# How to use options in dataTables initiated with aaData js array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have initialized my datatable with an `aaData` object and options like this:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable(dataTableObj, {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

The browser renders my table but does not activate the options. I've tried every combination but simply did not get any response from my table.

PS. my table works well. Especially with a large amount of data (23 cols and way more than 1000 rows).
**EDIT:**
thanks every one. the problem solved by slice the main object to 2 different objects for jquery dataTables. it needs `aaData` and `aoColumns`, both for data and column headers!

Comment: How are you specifying the columns? As per [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)  sample you should be specifying the data as a aaData parameter and the columns as an aaColumns parameter!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use datatable as per below code

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Shreya for formatting the code.I am new on stackoverflow, So i don't know how to format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it myself (and am proud of it :D).

broke down `dataTableObj` to 2 different objects for jquery dataTables. it needs aaData and aoColumns, both for data and column headers! something like this:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": dataCnt,
    "aoColumns": columnsHd
});
```